# How to wrap a third-party script in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have some third party scripts that I cannot update. One script defines some global functions while another uses those functions.

```
// script 'theirs.php'
function SomeFunction(...){}
```

My script also has a global function with the same name.

```
// script 'mine.php'
function SomeFunction(...){}
```

Is it possible to 'wrap' their code inside a name space?

```
<?php
namespace Their\Code;

include 'theirs.php'
?>
```

So that my script can call my function as per normal and their function if I need to.

```
<?php
// script somefile.php
use Their\Code;

now call their other file that expects their function.
include 'theirotherfile.php';
?>

<?php
// script 'theirotherfile.php'
// that file will be using the namespace Their\Code and not my functions.
SomeFunction(...);
?>
```

So is it possible to define the functions as part of a namespace.

```
<?php
namespace Their\Code;

include 'theirs.php'
?>
```

And then is is possible to call 'use' with a included file.

Comment: Why don't you use a name space for your function?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch, Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Obviously you have a collision for `\SomeFunction()`. You will have to move one of those functions into a different namespace. As you have no influence on the third party declaration you can just declare a namespace for yours, e.g. `mine\SomeFunction()`.